# Adding rows from CSV to new file

Tags: python, sum, summary

Hello i am looking to summerize and add numbers to a document reading from a CSV file.

For example my csv looks like this

```
Date,Customer number,Customer,Project number,Project,Worked time
2020,2020010,Apple,12345,Buying laptops,1,00
2020,2020010,Apple,12345,Buying laptops,4,00
2020,2020010,Apple,12345,Buying laptops,3,00
2020,2020010,Nokia,98738,Buying phones,1,00
2020,2020010,Nokia,98738,Buying phones,4,00
2020,2020010,Apple,12345,Buying laptops,3,00
```

i want to output this to a csv file and make the script summarize the numbers of worked time from each customer like this

Apple , 11
Nokia, 5

all i have so far is this

```
 
results = []
with open('Time_export.csv') as File:
    reader = csv.DictReader(File)
    for row in reader:
        results.append(row)
    print (results)
```

i am rookie at this :)
Been trying to google it but cant figure it out :(
Any thoughts?

Comment: Your header has 6 columns, but your rows have 7 columns. Things don't seem lined up here. Is worked time "1,00" (note the comma)? If so, that's not a valid CSV file, the comma should be escaped. This makes it harder go get columns right on csv readers.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary to store the customer names and totals:

```
import csv

data = '''
Date,Customer number,Customer,Project number,Project,Worked time
2020,2020010,Apple,12345,Buying laptops,1,00
2020,2020010,Apple,12345,Buying laptops,4,00
2020,2020010,Apple,12345,Buying laptops,3,00
2020,2020010,Nokia,98738,Buying phones,1,00
2020,2020010,Nokia,98738,Buying phones,4,00
2020,2020010,Apple,12345,Buying laptops,3,00
'''.strip()

with open('Time_export.csv','w') as f: f.write(data)  # write test file

################################

cust = {}  # customer totals

with open('Time_export.csv') as File:
    reader = csv.DictReader(File)
    for row in reader:
        if row['Customer'] in cust:
           cust[row['Customer']] += int(row['Worked time'])
        else:
           cust[row['Customer']] = int(row['Worked time'])
        
    print (cust)
```

Output

```
{'Apple': 11, 'Nokia': 5}
```

If you want to try Pandas, the code gets smaller:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('Time_export.csv', index_col=False )
df['Worked time'] = df['Worked time'].astype(int)
gb = df.groupby('Customer')["Worked time"].sum().reset_index()
print(gb.to_string(index=False))
```

Output

```
Customer  Worked time
   Apple           11
   Nokia            5
```

Answer (score 0):

I find `collections.defaultdict` useful for this type of thing. It automatically creates new key/value pairs as needed. In this case, defaulting to `int` which creates `0` as needed.

```
import csv
import collections

with open('Time_export.csv') as File:
    results = collections.defaultdict(int)
    reader = csv.DictReader(File)
    for row in reader:
        results[row['Customer']] += int(row['Worked time'])

for name, num in sorted(results.items()):
    print(f"{name}: {num}")
```

Answer (score 0):

[`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) is a powerful library for working on tables. Its hard to learn, but worth the effort. Your data uses a comma in the "Worked time" column, making it invalid CSV. If that were changed to "." or properly escaped, then you could do the work in a few lines of code.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Time_export.csv')
sums = df.groupby("Customer")["Worked time"].sum()
```

This groups by the customer, drops all but the "Worked time" column and then sums the group. The result is a series object that behaves much like a dict:

```
>>> print(sums)
Customer
Apple    11.0
Nokia     5.0
Name: Worked time, dtype: float64
>>> for name, val in sorted(sums.items()):
...     print(name, val)
... 
Apple 11.0
Nokia 5.0
>>> print(sums["Apple"])
11.0
```